# Flow failing when waiting for a platform event

Tags: visual-workflow, platform-event

I have designed an auto-launched flow that hits a waiting element and waits until a platform event is published to resume its execution.

At the moment it only works if the user has the 'modify all data' permission. If this permission is not enabled the flow will fail and it won't display the "The interview is now waiting" generic message. Instead of that, it will show an empty box. The execution is the same but it will fail once it hits the wait element for waiting for these platform events.

I have checked all the object permissions and everything seems alright. I would appreciate if somebody can help me with this.

Comment: The only workaround at the moment is adding another wait element between the element that fails and the new element. This doesn't feel intuitive at all and it should not be handled this way.

Comment: why not have the flow check for necessary permissions first and route logic accordingly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer copredy. I have checked the permissions and the problem seems unrelated to it or it might be that I am missing something really small. I think it is a platform issue with the platform events. I don't get any trace about a permissions issue in the logs. The error happens once the flow hits that wait element.